# Spark-submit fails with ClassNotFoundException for IterableCodecProvider

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to submit a .jar application on a Spark cluster using spark-submit. The binary used is
*spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7*

The issue arising when submitting is that the application fails with the exception:

```
$:/path-to-spark-binary/spark-submit --class Main --master local[*] app.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/codecs/IterableCodecProvider
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<clinit>(MongoClient.java:85)
at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:829)
at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:183)
```

The application interfaces with a remote MongoDB database using a MongoClient object. When a new MongoClient object is created, the application fails with the previous error.

I am using Maven to create the uber-jar containing all the dependencies. I am using the mongo-java-driver.jar library [from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.2)

I should also mention that the application runs normally when being executing without Spark on the remote server:

```
java -jar app.jar // ok
```

And it also runs normally when being submitted locally on my personal computer with the same Spark binary

I have discovered that the app does not fail when creating a new IterableCodecProvider object  but only when a new MongoClient object is created. Is this a static initialization issue ? Are there any other ways for interfacing with a MongoDB database without the aforementioned library ?

Edit 1: Code that generates exception:

```
try (SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .config("spark.master", "local")
                    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", Constants.sparkMongoDatabaseURI)
                    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", Constants.sparkMongoDatabaseURI)
                    .appName("Spark Session 1").getOrCreate()) {

                JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

                MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(Constants.dbMongoURI);
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

                ...
}
```

Edit 2: I have tried using spark-shell as well, but these same commands generate the exact same exception:

```
$:/path-to-spark-binary/spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.01:2.0.0

import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark;

sc.stop()

val sc2 = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("shell").set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://my_host:my_port/my_database.my_collection"))

MongoSpark.load(sc2)
```

Edit 3: Classpath

I have printed the classpath during runtime using the code:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

    for(URL url: urls){
        System.out.println(url.getFile());
    }
```

After applying grep on the results using "mongo" as keyword, these .jars were shown:

```
$SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-mongodb_2.11-0.12.0.jar
$SPARK_HOME/jars/mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar
$SPARK_HOME/jars/mongo-hadoop-spark-2.0.2.jar
```

The pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudera.sparkts/sparkts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudera.sparkts</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkts</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: P. S. : App fails regardless of the major version of the mongo driver used whether it uses Mongo objects or MongoClient object

Comment: Do you have another Mongo Java Driver version on the class path?

Comment: Hello @Ross, I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: Your intuition was on point @Ross, it seemed to be a classpath issue, I will post a complete answer with the full description of the solution until tomorrow

Comment: I haven't currently posted the complete solution, I will do so during this week as I have to complete this project in two days.